# To use Discrete Fourier Transform to invert a covariance matrix

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

I am working on a problem that its difficult part is to invert a covariance matrix (in R). I could not use usual approches like SVD and Chol. Then, I decided to use a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) approach. But I couldn't understand how to apply the method, especially in R. So, your comments and possible examples in R, would be appreciated. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain why you cannot use the "usual approaches"?

Comment: First, using, for example, choleski decomposition lead to an error regarding singularity. Second, the structure of the matrix is circulant and using DFT would be recommended.

Answer (score 6):

A circulant is a matrix whose first column is a vector $x$ and its subsequent columns are obtained by rotation of one element to the right.  Here is R code to produce any circulant from its first column `x`:

```
rotate <- function(x,k) {c(tail(x,-k), head(x,k))}
circulant <- function(x) {
    n=length(x)
    apply(matrix(0:(n-1),1,n), 2, function(k) rotate(x,n-k))
} # Returns the circulant matrix of which x is the first column
```

For example,

```
> circulant(c(2,3,5,7))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    7    5    3
[2,]    3    2    7    5
[3,]    5    3    2    7
[4,]    7    5    3    2
```

It is inverted by changing to an eigenbasis.  The diagonal elements are the entries of the Fourier Transform of `x`, so we invert them individually and change back to the original basis:

```
reciprocal <- function(x) {i <- which(x!=0); x[i] <- 1/x[i]; x}
inverse.circulant <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)                  # x is the first column of the circulant
    i <- (0:(n-1)) %o% (1:n)        # Powers of exp(2 Pi I/n) in the eigenbasis q
    q <- matrix(exp(complex(real=-log(n)/2, imaginary=2*pi*i / n)), n, n)
    w <- reciprocal(fft(x))         # Reciprocals of nonzero eigenvalues
    Re(t(q) %*% diag(w) %*% Conj(q))# Convert back to the original basis
} # Returns a generalized inverse to circulant(x)
```

For example, we demonstrate this works by multiplying its output by the original circulant and checking that the identity matrix is obtained (up to negligible floating point error):

```
> a <- c(2,3,5,7)
> zapsmall(inverse.circulant(a) %*% circulant(a))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

---

Be aware that ill-conditioning will still plague this approach due to floating point roundoff in `fft`. That is why I have implemented a `reciprocal` function: it refuses to compute $1/x$ when $x=0$.  As such, `inverse.circulant` computes a *generalized* inverse, exactly as in `MASS::ginv`:

```
# The following determines a nonsingular but ill-conditioned circulant:
> (a <- c(1, -200000/200001, -2500000/500001, 5000000/1000003))
[1]  1.000000 -0.999995 -4.999990  4.999985

> 1 / rcond(circulant(a)) # HUGE condition number!
[1]  5.404306e+16

> library(MASS)
> inverse.circulant(a) - ginv(circulant(a))
             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,] 6.938894e-18 -2.081668e-17 -4.163336e-17  2.775558e-17
[2,] 1.387779e-17 -6.938894e-18 -3.469447e-18  1.387779e-17
[3,] 1.387779e-17  4.163336e-17 -6.938894e-18  1.040834e-17
[4,] 3.469447e-17 -2.775558e-17 -1.387779e-17 -2.081668e-17
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer. However, when I ran your code to test it works properly, for checking identity matrix, I got this error: "Error in t(q) %*% w : non-conformable arguments"

Comment: Sorry; I made a typo when I introduced the `reciprocal` function as an afterthought.  In so doing I left out the call to `diag`.  I fixed this, copied the text of the edited message into R, and ran the examples again as a test.

Comment: awesome! I didn’t know anything of all that.

Comment: Elvis: as the Wikipedia article helpfully points out, circulants can be viewed as elements of the left regular representation of the group algebra of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  Everything follows from that via the theory of group representations.  Having an FFT available doesn't really speed things up asymptotically: at best, it halves the computation time.

Comment: Thank you so much whuber. The code has still an error. For checking it, the line "a <- circulant(c(2,3,5,7))" could be "a <- c(2,3,5,7)". Best.

Comment: Thanks; you're right.  Of course I needed to fix that during testing, and I did, but I have not been good at translating back and forth between R and text today!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a correction- by adding a small $\epsilon$ perturbation to the diagonal of the matrix you are trying to invert. This is a standard processing routine used to defer the singularity issue while inverting a covariance matrix or a hessian.

Comment: Yes, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Can you tell us the (reciprocal) condition number of your matrix? In R, you can do rcond(A).

Answer (score 1):

Is [the Wikipedia article on circulant matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) clear? This is something that in a time series context is discussed, for instance, in the first pages of [Hannan's Time Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412204800) book. The eigenvalues of a circulant matrix are given by the Fourier transform of what (again in a time series context) would be the autocovariances. So to invert the matrix you have to take the reciprocals of the eigenvalues and pre- and post-multiply by the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors.